# Filter duplicate records and push into array with additional condition using js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wan to filter the  list of objects where city and state are not same, and then create a list of cities out of the filtered objects where temperature is less than 40.
but condition is both sate and city should not be same

```
let arr = [
{
city:"chennai",
state: "tamilnadu",
temp: 44
},
 {
city:"coimbator",
state: "tamilnadu",
temp: 39
},
{
city:"mumbai",
state: "maharashtra",
temp: 32
},
{
city:"delhi",
state: "delhi",
temp: 24
},
{
city:"kolkata",
state: "west bengal",
temp: 28
}
];
```

Javascript code:

```
const uniqueStateCity = [];

const unique = arr.filter(element => {
const isDuplicate = uniqueStateCity.includes(element.city);
  
 if (!isDuplicate) {
  
  if(element.temp < 40)
  {
    uniqueStateCity.push(element.city );
    return true;
  
  }
}
  return false;
   
});

console.log(unique );
```

Comment: Is your snippet not working already ?

Comment: @pixlboy working but I am unable to check both state and city.. present code is filter only city.. but I want code in such a way it should filter state & city.

Comment: what is there are 2 cities in a same state with temperature less than 40 ?

Comment: you could have used a better input for your example that actually contains a duplicate

Comment: Its a poor example in code and question is not telling whether we should compare city and state in same object or with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks for uniqueness of `city` and `state` values and also handles your additional conditions. It will not add values which have the same `city` and the same `state` value as any other object in the array.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    city: "chennai",
    state: "tamilnadu",
    temp: 44,
  },
  {
    city: "coimbator",
    state: "tamilnadu",
    temp: 39,
  },
  {
    city: "mumbai",
    state: "maharashtra",
    temp: 32,
  },
  {
    city: "mumbai",
    state: "maharashtra",
    temp: 32,
  },
  {
    city: "delhi",
    state: "delhi",
    temp: 24,
  },
  {
    city: "kolkata",
    state: "west bengal",
    temp: 28,
  }
];

const result = arr.reduce((all, cur) => { 
  if (
    all.findIndex((c) => c.city === cur.city && c.state === cur.state) < 0 &&
    cur.state !== cur.city && 
    cur.temp < 40
  ) {
    all.push(cur);
  }

  return all;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this in your code!

just put condition in the result statement with arrow function and you are good to go.

```
    let arr = [
  {
    city: "chennai",
    state: "tamilnadu",
    temp: 44,
  },
  {
    city: "coimbator",
    state: "tamilnadu",
    temp: 39,
  },
  {
    city: "mumbai",
    state: "maharashtra",
    temp: 32,
  },
  {
    city: "delhi",
    state: "delhi",
    temp: 24,
  },
  {
    city: "kolkata",
    state: "west bengal",
    temp: 28,
  },
];

const result = arr.filter((data) => data.temp < 40 && data.state !== data.city);
const data = result.map((x) => x.city);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This doesn't check for uniqueness as OP originally implemented it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree but you can see I just used filter to print it while you do not need map function for it.

Comment: @KishanDobariya please check my updated question  even check for state also different

Comment: Yeah, Let me take a look back on this and I will edit my answer.

Thank you for response

Comment: @user_1234 I updated my Answer. Please check it.

Comment: @KishanDobariya no it is not working  but i didn't understand 2nd logic i.e map .. how it is filtering the city and state in map ??

Comment: yeah I can understand please try on your side it actually worked for me. The 2nd logic of map is just to filter out only city fields because ultimately you want to print the cities as a answer with your conditions. so in result we get city, temp, state by filtering out them according to your conditions right now after that if we want to print only city as a answer of that conditions we need to make a map function and map used for returning the new array so what i did is i created the variable of data and passed result in it and then used map function to get only city by using arrow function.

Comment: OP wants full object in array and not just city names.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    city: "chennai",
    state: "tamilnadu",
    temp: 44,
  },
  {
    city: "coimbator",
    state: "tamilnadu",
    temp: 39,
  },
  {
    city: "mumbai",
    state: "maharashtra",
    temp: 32,
  },
  {
    city: "mumbai",
    state: "maharashtra",
    temp: 32,
  },
  {
    city: "delhi",
    state: "delhi",
    temp: 24,
  },
  {
    city: "kolkata",
    state: "west bengal",
    temp: 28,
  },
];
const result = [
...new Set(
arr.filter((data) => data.temp < 40 && data.state !== data.city).map((data) => data.city)
)
];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to filter out the objects having same names for city and state and with temperature greater than 40.

Also if your original `arr` has duplicate objects, and you want an array of unique objects. You can use:

```
const result = arr.filter(data => data.temp < 40 && data.state !== data.city);

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < result.length; ++j) {
        if ( i !== j && 
             result[i].city === result[j].city && 
             result[i].state === result[j].state && 
             result[i].temp === result[j].temp
        ) {
            result.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
}
```